# Syntax error in /etc/default/console-setup when running "sudo update-initramfs -u -k 5.19.0-31-generic"

Tags: kernel, dpkg, initramfs

When executing the command `sudo update-initramfs -u -k 5.19.0-31-generic`, I encountered a syntax error related to the `/etc/default/console-setup` file.

The specific error message states:

```
/etc/default/console-setup: syntax error: "(" unexpected". This error prevents the successful generation of the initramfs image.
```

I am seeking assistance from the community to resolve this issue. I have already attempted to reinstall the console-setup package, but the problem persists. How can I overcome this syntax error and generate the initramfs image successfully?

I wish I could more of the error but the error is happning in my another laptop.

Comment: Please check the contents of the file - it could be something simple like a comment line mentioning `the console-setup(5) manual page` having been uncommented